# When Bluetooth is enabled youtube/spotify/soundcloud stops working

Tags: bluetooth

Since last week I had a really strange issue.
Please note that before everything worked fine.

When I connect/enable my Bluetooth headphones everything HTML5 enabled like Spotify Soundcloud Youtube stops working.
When I disable/disconnect the Bluetooth headphone it starts playing immediately.

Comment: Bluetooth settings does not have an option for "only allow media, not phone". I disconnected and reconnected the earbud headset and I was able to play the youtube video and get audio through the earbud headset. Switching between audio sources allows the video/etc to play. I am wonderin if pipewire will get around this. OS: Ubuntu 21.10 x86_64 Host: Inspiron 7573 Kernel: 5.13.0-40-generic DE: Plasma 5.24.4 WM: kwin CPU: Intel i5-8250U (8) @ 3.400GHz GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 Memory: 2528MiB / 7690MiB

Answer (score 4):

i disabled the mic input 
and the mode was set to HSP and switched that back to A2DP
and my videos immediately started to play again

Comment: How did you disable the mic input?

Answer (score 2):

In Sound Settings, Output, select the Headset (bluetooth accessory) in the table on the left and change the mode to "Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)" and then change it to "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)" (even if it was already in this mode).

If bluetooth fails to pair when you fiddle with it, turn the bluetooth off and on in Bluetooth Settings.

Answer (score 0):

In the Bluetooth settings for the device, only allow Media, not Phone, and it will work.